# Pine Script - Dynamic Variables? (not necessarily correct terminology)

Tags: function, variables, dynamic, pine-script, procedure

```
//@version=5

tspy = 60

blue = color.new(color.blue,tspy)
```

now when this following code executes many lines below/later:

```
tspy := 0
plot(rsi, title='bullish', color=blue)
```

As would be expected this does not change the transparency of variable `blue` by itself, obviously I can put `blue := color.new(color.blue,0)`, but that is not ideal.

Is there a type of variable that is dynamic and will update itself whenever a variable contained within it changes, rather than having to manually re-execute the variables expression?

I have also tried setting the colours into a "function" call, but this seems to get complicated and causes more problems and code than just reentering/duplicating the original code. This may seem trivial, but it has a much wider importance and use case in more complex coding than this particular example.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a function?

```
//@version=5
indicator("My Script")

get_color(transp) => color.new(color.blue, transp)

plot(series=1, color=get_color(100))
plot(series=2, color=get_color(80))
plot(series=3, color=get_color(60))
plot(series=4, color=get_color(40))
plot(series=5, color=get_color(20))
```

[image]